# I can't get my new to do list item to post.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying to follow the steps to get my do make a to do list. Everything has been going smoothly until I submit my item. I keep getting a error saying "ArgumentError in ItemsController#create, wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)". It highlights the second line under my create method saying thats where the problem is. My code in my controllers look like so.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
   @user = params[:id].blank? ? current_user : User.find(params[:id])
   @items = @user.items
  end
end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @items = @user.items.create(params.require[:items].permit(:name))
  redirect_to @user
 end
end
```

I am not sure why it's giving me a arguments error. I have been following a video, and theirs is working, so i'm stumped. Also I don't know if you need to see my db migrate but here it is:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :items do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

   t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

end
If anyone could help me out I would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Try changing `@items = @user.items.create(params.require[:items].permit(:name))` to `@items = @user.items.create(params.require(:item).permit(:name))`

Comment: Thanks soooooo much!!! I was going crazy haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ArgumentError in ItemsController#create, wrong number of arguments (0
>   for 1)

As I aid, it should be

```
@items = @user.items.create(params.require(:item).permit(:name))
```

Also, to go by with *Rails way*, you can call it by a *private method* like below

```
#items_controller

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @items = @user.items.create(item_params)
    redirect_to @user
  end

  private
  def item_params
    @items = @user.items.create(params.require(:item).permit(:name))
  end
end
```

Comment: You saved me! I am really thankful that you took the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@items = @user.items.create(params.require[:items].permit(:name))
```

with

```
@items = @user.items.create(params.require(:item).permit(:name))
```

in your `ItemsController` `create` method.